# Recycler view in fragment is empty

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have converted an activity to fragment. The activity parses JSON data and displays it in recycler view. In  activity it was working fine. I converted it to a fragment, but now it shows a blank screen. please help me solve this.
My repository link [link]https://github.com/muhammednasimda/actvityfragment

Comment: add your activity code and fragment codes here.

Comment: Can you post code here or, at least, say what file should we see

Comment: you haven't added your list to the adapter. Call setAdapter() first

Comment: You should add the code here for us not to have to go elsewhere to find it. Add only **relevant** code, not whole project

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
parseJson();
mExampleAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(getContext(), mExampleList);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mExampleAdapter);
```